# My Linux machine reboot everyday at 0:00 UTC but I never set that. What could cause this happen?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and it auto reboots every day. There is a broadcast message in the terminal before rebooting, like the following:

```
Broadcast message from root@ec2... (Sun 2021-03-28 00:01:50 UTC):

The system is going down for reboot at Sun 2021-03-28 00:02:50 UTC!
```

I have never set an auto reboot thing as far as I know. Is there a way I could see what caused the reboot, or somehow disable the reboot?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `/var/log/cron` or `/var/log/daemon` or one of the other logfiles in `/var/log` at around midnight timestamp - perhaps one of them will give you a clue what’s going on.

Also check `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*` - my bet is that there’s a cron job running at midnight every day that among other things reboots the instance.